# Create a new game object on key input

Tags: java

I've been able to make my spaceship shoot a lazer object and once the lazer is off the screen it just resets the object to the original position, but I want to make the lazer object not rely on being off-screen before I can shoot again. So how do I make my spaceship shoot a lazer every time the up key is pressed? In other words, create a new lazer object everytime up key is pressed and shoot it, instead of having to reset the one lazer object over and over.

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5794099463789882206L;

public static final int WIDTH = 1300, HEIGHT = 700;

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;

private Random ra;
private Handler handler;
public static int posX = 368;
public static int posY = 500;
private HUD hud;
private Laz lazer;
private Laz lazer1;
private Laz lazer2;
private Laz[] laz;
private static int in;

public Game(){

    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LEGGO SPAGHETTIO", this);
    handler = new Handler();
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    ra = new Random();
    hud = new HUD();
    for(int i = 0; i<300; i++){
    handler.addObject(new Player2(ra.nextInt(WIDTH), ra.nextInt(HEIGHT*5), ID.Player2));
    }

    lazer = new Laz();
    lazer1 = new Laz();
    lazer2 = new Laz();
    laz = new Laz[] {lazer, lazer1, lazer2};
    handler.addObject(new Player(posX, posY, ID.Player));

        //handler.addObject(new Lazer(posX, posY, ID.Lazer));
        handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(posX, posY, ID.BasicEnemy));


    }


public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;

}

public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running = false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void run()
{
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running)
    {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                while(delta >=1)
                        {
                            tick();
                            delta--;
                        }
                        if(running)
                            render();
                        frames++;

                        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
                        {
                            timer += 1000;
                          //  System.out.println("FPS: "+ frames);
                            frames = 0;
                        }
    }
            stop();
            }
private void tick(){
    handler.tick();
    hud.tick();
    if(KeyInput.up_key_pressed){
        laz[in].shoot();
    }






}

private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    handler.render(g);
    hud.render(g);
    laz[in].render(g);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game(); 
}
```

}

```
    public class Laz {
private int y = 650;
private int velY = 10;

public void tick(){

}
public void render(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(150, y, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}
public void shoot(){
y-=velY;
}}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at solving this yourself? Nothing in this code looks like it is trying to create a new object on keypress

Comment: I created lazer 1, 2 and 3 and then put them into an array and attempt to access them 1 by one in my tick method. I've tried so many different ways to do this correctly but haven't been able to figure it out for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an List of your class Laz, and then add a new Laz whenever you need one. It will then be up to you to implement a way to be able to access a laser object if you need it before it is off screen, as well as a method to remove them from the array list when they need to be removed